# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ku.aajakobazzar.MainActivity error

Tags: java, android

In method onlistitemclick... try block is not working....and exception is being caught causing

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ku.aajakobazzar.MainActivity error

my code is

```
package com.ku.aajakobazzar;


public class Mainmenu extends ListActivity {

String classes[] = { "ViewPrice" , "UpdatePrice" , "Preferences" , "Exit" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Mainmenu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String choose =classes[position];
    try{
        Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.ku.aajakobazzar." + choose);
        Intent ourinIntent = new Intent(Mainmenu.this, ourclass);
        startActivity(ourinIntent);

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: The Class `com.ku.aajakobazzar.MainActivity` is not in your project dependencies accordingly.